# How do I change the video settings in Mirror's Edge?

Tags: mirrors-edge

I need to turn off PhysX because I go from 60fps to 1fps every time any glass breaks.
The video settings are all grayed out and locked except for contrast and brightness for some reason.

How do you change the video settings in Mirror's Edge?

Comment: Are you in the middle of playing the game?  I think when I did that I needed to close and restart the game.

Comment: @tugs i'll see if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem thanks to @tugs:

You cannot change video settings while in game, exit to the main menu and video options will be enabled for changing.